# Opening a tex file with texmaker by doubleclicking it renders building unuseable

Tags: miktex, texmaker

I may be missing something pretty obvious here but here goes:

I have a portable version of MiKTEX unzipped in my C drive.
I have TexMaker portable in the C drive as well.
Running TexWorks that came with MiKTEX works fine.
Starting TexMaker and opening a *.tex file compiles fine.

However, setting all *.tex files to open with TexMaker* by doubleclicking renders compiling unuseable. I get this error:

```
Could not start the command. "texmfs/install/miktex/bin/pdflatex.exe - synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"
```

Why is that?

Because I have multiple projects in different folders I would prefer to just go into the folder and double click on a file to edit, instead of opening TexMaker and looking for the file from there.

- MikTex is always open in system tray.

Comment: Can't you add miktex to your path variable? Beside this: How do you open texmaker when it works? Throught the miktex system tray?

Comment: Ulrike wouldn't that defeat the purpose of portability? I open texmaker by either running texmaker.exe file, or through a shortcut pointing to that exe. To set the tex files to open directly with texmaker I right clicked, selected open as and pointed to texmaker.exe. Also Moriambar I read the starter guide but can't seem to see how this question does not comply. Any pointers?

Comment: Sure it defeats portability, but setting the path would make it easier to run the applications. If you want to avoid it you will have to find out why texmaker sets the path when you open it directly -- or write a small batch script that sets the path and then calls texmaker. Butw: when you want to notify someone you should use an at sign: @UlrikeFischer